# Plain text JSP response

Tags: jsp, glassfish, response, plaintext

I'm stuck on this problem. The answer might be straight forward, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

Here is my very simple jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain" 
import="java.util.*" 
import="subscriberapi.SubscriberAPI"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%!private String Check(String jsonText)
{
    SubscriberAPI subscriberAPI = new SubscriberAPI();
    return subscriberAPI.Check(jsonText);
}%>
<%response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("pragma","no-cache");%>
<%=Check(request.getParameter("jsonText"))%>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
{"Status":true,"Message":"All good"}
```

But the output I get is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"Status":true,"Message":"All good"}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks correct in a browser but the actual response goes to another process, that doesn't want the html.

How do I get rid of the html build around the response?
Is this set by Glassfish?

Comment: Not an answer (I've never seen this before), but a workaround (actually, the *right* solution) would be to use a Servlet instead of a JSP. You're here basically abusing JSP for non-HTML content.

Comment: I'll have a look at Servlet then, I needed a quick (and dirty) solution.

Comment: @TungstenX I am stuck with exactly the same problem, but i am using a dispatcher servlet. Could I get some more help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

:blush: Epic fail!

When Google Chrome is presented with *text/plain* it will wrap it in html (as above).  I feel like such a noob developer. I should have checked it on other browsers and or wrote a test app.  In any case, I followed BalusC advice and made a Servlet

Comment: Interesting, didn't knew that either. Note that for JSON you should actually be using `application/json` not `text/plain`.

Comment: Holy cow! you're right. Just checked it out with Fiddler and it's true.

Answer (score -1):

What web container are you using? tried this in Apache Tomcat 6.24. I changed your method to return a hard-coded json string. worked OK with no html markup around output.

Inspect your request parameter and review what your SubscriberAPI::Check method is doing

Comment: Glassfish v2.  The request parameter and the java code is good.  It returns a json string (no html included)